# WebOrb to record from my webcam

Tags: stream, record, weborb

Can WebOrb record a video (flv) streaming using the webcam as a source? How?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44143/publishing-flash-video) they talk about this.

On the weborb site i found [this](http://www.themidnightcoders.com/index.php?id=120) entry, so it can be done, but apperently they haven't updated their site yet with an example...

Comment: Hi, I found that one too. It is very strange they don't tell you HOW to do it. About the same on the FluorineFX website.

Answer (score 0):

As of WebORB 4.2 this is a definite yes if your referring to WebORB.Net and their is an included example of this in the latest installers